# How to add keyboard shortcuts / accelerator keys for a menu item created by a Gedit plugin

Tags: python, gtk, keyboard-shortcuts, pygtk, gedit

I created a Gedit 2 plugin which adds an item to a menu as described [here](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/PythonPluginHowToOld#Adding_a_menu_item). How could I bind a keyboard shortcut / accel key / accelerator key to this menu item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the given tutorial, your plugin have some lines like the ones below somewhere:

```
self._action_group = gtk.ActionGroup("ExamplePyPluginActions")
self._action_group.add_actions([("ExamplePy", None, _("Clear document"),
         None, _("Clear the document"),
         self.on_clear_document_activate)])
manager.insert_action_group(self._action_group, -1)
```

Just replace the second `None`  argument in

```
self._action_group.add_actions([("ExamplePy", None, _("Clear document"),
        None, _("Clear the document"),
        self.on_clear_document_activate)])
```

by your desired keyboard shortcut - let us say, <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

```
self._action_group.add_actions([("ExamplePy", None, _("Clear document"),
        "<control>r", _("Clear the document"), # <- here
        self.on_clear_document_activate)])
```

You may have used a manually constructed action as well (this is at least my favorite way of working with it):

```
action = gtk.Action("ExamplePy", 
        _("Clear document"), 
        _("Clear the document"), None)
action.connect("activate", self.on_open_regex_dialog)
action_group = gtk.ActionGroup("ExamplePyPluginActions")
action_group.add_action(action)
```

In this case, just replace `action_group.add_action()`  by `action_group.add_action_with_accel()`:

```
action_group = gtk.ActionGroup("ExamplePyPluginActions")
action_group.add_action_with_accel(action, "<control>r")
```

(Asked and aswered by myself because of [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to/17467#17467); I lost some real time looking for it and I thought it will be a good reference.)

Comment: Any idea if/how I can use a shortcut like "<control>0"? I tried "<control>zero" too, but none of them work.